# ArrayIndexOutofBoundException with ArrayList in ListView in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, indexoutofboundsexception

I am using one ListView and set the one adapter with two Arraylist. List and List1 is two ArrayList which is different different GetAllItems from SqliteDatabase.

My Question is , List have Suppose 10 Items and List1 have 7 Items then when I Scrolling my Listview and Successfully display item upto 7 but whenever 8th item then Give the error ArrayOutOfBoundExcecption. Because Different size of both ArrayList. List is Always Larger then List1.

How to solve This error?

Plesae guide me.

```
My code is, 

    Adapter1 adapter = new Adapter1(this,
                            List, List1);
    listView1.setAdapter(Adapter1);

        dbAdapter.openForRead();
            list = dbAdapter.getAllMyData();
            dbAdapter.close();

            dbAdapter.openForRead();

            list1 = dbAdapter.getDisplayLike();
            dbAdapter.close();


/** Adapter Class */
    public class Adapter1 extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context = null;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;

        List<List> list = new ArrayList<List>();
        List<List1> list1 = new ArrayList<List1>();

        public Adapter1(Context context, List<List> list ,
                List<List1> list1 ) {

            this.context = context;
            this.list  = list ;
            this.list1 = list1;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;
            if (vi == null) {
                vi = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,
                        parent, false);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                /** Initialize Widgets */
                /** Imageview */
                viewHolder.imgUserIcon = (ImageView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgUserIcon);
                viewHolder.imgImage = (ImageView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgImage);

                viewHolder.imgUnlike = (ImageView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgUnlike);
                viewHolder.imgUnlike.setTag(position);

                viewHolder.imgLike = (ImageView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgLike);
                viewHolder.imgLike.setTag(position);



                /** TextView */
                viewHolder.txtPostId = (TextView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtPostId);
                viewHolder.txtUserName = (TextView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
                viewHolder.txtDateTime = (TextView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtDateTime);


                viewHolder.txtLikeUnlike = (TextView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtLikeUnlike);
                viewHolder.txtLikeUnlike.setTag(position);


                vi.setTag(viewHolder);

            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }



            final List listBean= list .get(position);
            final List1 list1Bean= list1.get(position);


            viewHolder.txtPostId.setText(listBean.getiPostId()
                    + "");
            viewHolder.txtUserName.setText(listBean.getName());

            viewHolder.txtDateTime.setText(listBean.getStrCreated());

            viewHolder.txtLikeUnlike.setText(listBean.getiLike()
                    + "");



            int iDisplayLike = list1Bean.getiDisplayLike();
            if (iDisplayLike == 1) {
                viewHolder.imgUnlike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.imgLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            if (iDisplayLike == 0) {
                viewHolder.imgLike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.imgUnlike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            });
            return vi;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imgIcon = null, imgImage = null,
                    imgUnlike = null;
            TextView txtPostId = null, txtUserName = null,
                    txtDateTime = null, 
                    txtLikeUnlike = null;
        }
```

Comment: why do you need 2 list? bind it in single list with and use model class or hashmap list

Comment: post your adapter here...

Comment: @Ravi beacuse I used two table for Fetching data so I have used two ArrayList

Comment: check ur getSize() method in your Adapter class, what size you given there.

Comment: if you use 2 list with different size thn it will  create problem

Comment: @Ravi Ya exactly I used two List so Create This Problem

Comment: @Ram Wait I send you Adapter Class

Comment: @Reena problem is in you your adapter getcount method.is seems your getcount is 10 for list and in list1 contains only 8 items check with postion like if(list1.size<=position){ here  update your UI for list1 data}

Comment: @Reena check edited answer once.

Comment: @Ram please explain in detail in my code. where is updated in my code

Comment: chek in getview  i added this code if(list1.size()<postion)
             {
              int iDisplayLike = list1Bean.getiDisplayLike();
            if (iDisplayLike == 1) {
                viewHolder.imgUnlike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.imgLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            if (iDisplayLike == 0) {
                viewHolder.imgLike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.imgUnlike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
             }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68631/discussion-between-ram-and-reena).

Answer (score 0):

if you are fetching data from two tables then first marge both `ArrayList` then pass single `ArrayList` in adapter to show data instead of two List.

In `Adapter1` class constructor marge both ArrayList:

```
private ArrayList<DataType> finalList;
 public Adapter1(Context mContext,ArrayList list1,ArrayList list2){
  finalList = new ArrayList<DataType>(list1);
  finalList.addAll(list2);
}
```

Now use `finalList` for in `getView` and `getCount` methods of Adapter where you are using `List` and `List1`